# Delete database tables with php\mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to list all the tables in a database into an array and then proceed to delete the tables contents. What is wrong with my code?

```
    <?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','');

mysql_select_db(database_name);

$res = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES");

$tables = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $tables[] = "$row[0]";
}

$length = count($tables);

for ($i = 1; $i < $length; $i++) {
  $res = "DELETE FROM $tables[$i]";
  mysql_query($res);
  echo $res;
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: What errors do you get? What debugging have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your for loop you don't need to do $i++; anymore, as this operation is already included in the for loop.

The code you have at the moment will delete the contents of one table and then skip a table, delete contents of one table again and skip one again...

Also $i should start with 0 as the first element in an array in php is element 0.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $res = "DELETE FROM $tables[$i]";
    mysql_query($res);
    echo $res;
}
```